# Facebook API page subscription

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to subscribe other's Facebook user's page to my application. Application has permissions like pages_messaging, public_profile, etc. Basically this is a messenger. But it complains and keep saying that I need a "manage_pages" permission. Why? I can't find docs in FB api regarding it. Thanks

Comment: _“But it complains and keep saying that I need a "manage_pages" permission. Why?”_ – well likely because, contrary to what you _think_, you _don’t_ “have it”.

Comment: This answer is working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690731/how-to-subscribe-a-fb-page-to-a-facebook-app

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should apply for manage pages permission in your app.To create a subscription you should have the manage_pages permission.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps