# How to subscribe a FB page to a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to subscribe a Facebook page to my facebook app. It's a messenger app where I need to subscribe the page to my webhook added in the app.

Using the graph API, I have the page access token and page id, I have tried the subscribed_apps API but it didn't work

```
 FB.api('/' + page.id+ '/subscribed_apps?access_token=' + 
         page.access_token,function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        });
```

Is there an API to make the page to subscribe to my webhook in the app.

Comment: You can also use the Graph API Explorer tool to quickly try out API calls: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'didn't work'? Did the API throw and error of some sort? Can you add those details to the question as well?

Comment: You need to make a POST request - right now you are using GET.

Answer (score 3):

It is described in the Graph API reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Creating

Comment: Adding a brief summary of the process would make this answer a million times more helpful.

Comment: Send a POST to `me/subscribed_apps` with the page access token to subscribe. To delete a subscription you only need to send a DELETE request - same endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the below API to subscribe the page to your webhook. Specify the fields you want to subscribe to using the subscribed_fields query parameter depends on your use case.

```
`curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/subscribed_apps
?subscribed_fields=feed
&access_token={page-access-token}"`
```

Example - If your use-case is related to page messaging use *messages,message_echoes* fields as subscribed_fields.

Note - Your page access token should have **pages_messaging** permission.